# Ansi C and Temporary Files

Tags: c, c99, c89, gcc-pedantic

I need the integer file descriptor from a temporary file to be used in mmap. This need may need to change if there's no simple way to do this while still being standards compliant.

I originally got a FILE stream using:

```
FILE *tmpfile();
```

and then used...

```
int fileno(FILE foo);
```

All was good until I noticed the following in the man page for fileno.

```
CONFORMING TO
   The functions clearerr(), feof(), and ferror() conform to C89 and C99.
```

ie **fileno** is not part of c99. I've had a look online for a simple way to get a temporary filename or it's file descriptor in a way that doesn't throw errors when using

```
-std=c99 -pedantic
```

and so far the best thing I've found is:

http://www.di-mgt.com.au/c_function_to_create_temp_file.html

I'd love to know what other people are doing to get around this and is there a man page that I've missed somewhere or something obvious I can use in c99 that I've overlooked?

Update: I wrote a small test program to see where I went wrong. Please forgive the lack of error checking, I'm trying to keep it short. I've run this using clang and gcc on a Debian box:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, const char* const argv[]) 
{   
  const char *fname = argv[1];
  /*  
   FILE *stream  = fopen("foo", "wb+");
   -std=c99 -pedantic fails on fileno
   int fd = fileno(stream);
  */
  int fd ;
  if((fd = open(fname, O_RDWR| O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fd=%i, failed: %s\n",fd, strerror (errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }   
  size_t fsize = 27; 
  char *buf;
  lseek (fd, fsize  - 1, SEEK_SET);
  write (fd, "", 1); 
  lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  buf = mmap(0, fsize, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
  size_t i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
    buf[i] = i % 26 + 97; 
  }   
  buf[26] = '\n';
  munmap(buf, fsize);
  close(fd);
  return argc;//Avoid warnings about unused variables
}
```

The run it with either with clang or gcc using **Beware** the **rm -f** at the start of the command.

```
rm -f foo mmap; clang -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition mmap.c -o mmap;./mmap foo;cat foo|wc -c

rm -f foo mmap; gcc   -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition mmap.c -o mmap;./mmap foo;cat foo|wc -c
```

This works which means I'm missing something about the use of -std=c99 -pedantic because I would expect it to fail miserably when I tried to include any non standard header ie in this case I would have expected errors trying to include these...

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

I'd be interested in knowing why the above programs compiles ie is something being set in the headers that's turning off warnings or am I abusing gcc?

Comment: The lower-level file descriptors are a POSIX thing.

Comment: You do realize that `mmap()` is not C99, it's POSIX? So there seems to be a contradiction here. You can't use `mmap()` if you only want to use things that are standard in C99.

Comment: This started with the following warning:  warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’. I'm not getting any warnings using mmap and I've got -std=c99 -pedantic so I've likely done something weird in my makefile.

Answer (score 4):

You can't achieve what you want.

The documentation for `-pedantic` says:

> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++.  For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

Integer file descriptors are not part of the C standard. They are from POSIX. Also, there is no `mmap` in the C standard, it comes from POSIX too. So the `-pedantic` flag is designed to not allow you to do what you want to do. I just checked the header files and compiler configuration on my system and they explicitly exclude (many, but not all) POSIX functions if you're compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`.

Are you sure you really want to use that flag?

To create a temporary file with standard C use `tmpfile` then instead of `mmap` you need to read and write the file with normal `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: `-pedantic` doesn't prevent the standard headers from declaring the functions in question, it's `-std=c99`. Should work with a `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1` before the first `#include` (even with `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors`). Additional library functions aren't "forbidden extensions" (e.g. converting from `void *` to a function pointer is).

Comment: Sure, you can work around `-pedantic`. But the question then still remains: "Are you sure you really want to use that flag?". Why create a problem and then solve it instead of not creating the problem in the first place?

Comment: My point was, that `-pedantic` isn't the problem, but `-std=c99`. Either you use `-std=gnu99` (which predefines some feature test macros) or define the feature test macros yourself.

Comment: As a possible motivation: You may want to use POSIX extensions, but no GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Via [`sort-bed`](https://github.com/bedops/bedops/blob/master/applications/bed/sort-bed/src/SortDetails.cpp#L117), here's one way that populates a `fileName` pointer with a temporary filename within `path` and returns a `FILE*`:

```
FILE *
createTmpFile(char const* path, char** fileName)
{
  FILE* fp;
  int fd;
  char* tmpl;

  if (path == NULL)
      {
          fileName = NULL;
          return tmpfile();
      }

  tmpl = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(path) + L_tmpnam);
  strcpy(tmpl, path);
  strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path), "/sb.XXXXXX");
  fd = mkstemp(tmpl);
  if(fd == -1)
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "unable to create temp file!\n");
          return NULL;
      }
  fp = fdopen(fd, "wb+");
  *fileName = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmpl) + 1);
  strcpy(*fileName, tmpl);
  free(tmpl);
  return fp;
}
```